# Reversing symbols in file name

Tags: character-encoding, virus, torrent

This is not really about programming, but I don't know where else to ask it. So I've just downloaded torrent with one file in it - the formal name of file should  be "123.avi.exe" (which is typical for viruses and trojans). Now, interesting thing is that name is encoded in UTF16-LE as following bytes:

```
FFFE3100320033002E002D202E202D202E206900760061002E00650078006500
```

which gives us strange, partially reversed over ".exe" text (try to move cursor left-to-right and you will be surprised):

```
123.‭‮‭‮iva.exe
```

But the bad part of all - is that utorrent showing non-suspicious ".avi" extension while when you double click it in GUI - it goes as as ".exe" and program runs.

You can test it yourself by creating dummy file with the name I wrote above. How can I protect myself from running files like that on system level?

P.S. I've started similar [thread](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/105938-partially-showed-filename-leads-to-starting-virus-executable) on uTorrent tracker (not yet approved by moderator)

Comment: What version of uTorrent did you use?

Comment: Latest at this moment

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because even the OP says it  not really about programming

Answer (score 0):

You have possibly found a active attack using a Remote Code Execution Vulnerability in uTorrent and other torrent clients. There has been similar vulnerabilities before: http://www.zerodayinitiative.com/advisories/ZDI-16-674/
It's probably a good idea to contact uTorrent and make them aware of the exploit.

What version of uTorrent do you use?
In general the best protection is to use the newest stable version of programs.
Even if newer uTorrent versions is infested with annoying advertisement, that can be deactivated.

This question may fit better at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Done: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159069/special-characters-in-filename-leads-to-starting-virus-executable